# Generic .htaccess for multiple websites stored in subdirectories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, host

My development environment is set up for using a single host (`localhost`). I am developing multiple websites on my machine, each stored under its own directory like this:

```
     /var/www/site1
     /var/www/site2
     ...
```

The document root is set to `/var/www` on my machine.

I am using URL rewriting for most of these websites and most of the `.htaccess` files will rewrite a sub-directory to **GET** parameters in different ways like this:

```
http://localhost/site1/home/red -> http://localhost/site1/index.php?page=home&p1=red
http://localhost/site2/index/param1/param2/param3 -> http://localhost/site2/index.php?page=index&p1=param1&p2=param2&p3=param3
```

I also tend to copy some of these websites under different directories and, when I do that, I have to make a lot of changes in the `.htaccess` files for the website that I'm copying.

I would like to know if there is a way to define a constant that contains the website's root directory (not the host's document root) and how can that be used with the rewrite rule so that I would need to change only one line of code (setting this constant to a different value) when copying a website.

Putting this in a different form, is there a way to perform rewrites that relate to a website root instead of a host / `%{HTTP_HOST}` (i.e. the "host" for the website being `localhost/site1` instead of `localhost`) and how can this be done?

I have tried removing the host from each request at the beginning of the script and prepending it back at the end of the script, but this does not work with rewrite rules that use the `[L]` option.

Thank you!

Regards,
Lucian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an htaccess file with rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site1/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) index.php?page=$1&p1=$2&p2=$3&p4=$4 [L,QSA]
```

And put this in the directory `/var/www/site1`, and if you want for it to apply to site2, change the `RewriteBase` and put the rules in `/var/www/site2`.